# How to create an object for a class and use its functions in one line

Tags: c#

Currently I'm using

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(ds));
```

So what is the shorthand form the the same?
I remember seeing `Serialize` called in one line itself in one of the questions in stackoverflow, but i forgot where i saw that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't assign it to an intermediate variable.

```
context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ds));
```